# How to use scientific operator E with Variables?

Tags: java

I declared a double variable as below:

```
double x=56.27d
```

And then all I tried to do is the following: (56.27*10*10)

```
System.out.println(xE2);
```

And this is not working.

Comment: You can use that notation with literals, but not with variables. ie double y = 1e2; is fine.

Comment: Thanks dear. So, how do I go about solving a certain type of problem. Example, I received a user input of 56.27 and now I want to display the result on screen as 56.27*10*10. How to do? Kindly help.

Comment: Put the number into a double variable, then multiply it by 100. double n = 56.27 * 100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        double d = sc.nextDouble(); // Get input from the user
        System.out.println(d * 10 * 10);

        // Displaying it using scientific notation
        // Format the number rounded up to two places after decimal and into scientific notation
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2e", d * 10 * 10));

        // Examples of e or E with double literals
        double x = 1e2; // 1 * 10 to the power of 2 = 100.0
        System.out.println(x);
        double y = 1E2; // 1 * 10 to the power of 2 = 100.0
        System.out.println(y);
        double z = 1e+02; // 1 * 10 to the power of 2 = 100.0
        System.out.println(z);
        System.out.println(d * 1e2);// i.e. d * 100.0
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a number: 56.27
5627.0
5.63e+03
100.0
100.0
100.0
5627.0
```

**Notes:**

1. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) to learn more about `Formatter`.
2. `E` or `e` can be used only with double literals, not double variables.

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: First of all thanks for taking the pain to explain. Very nervous to admit that I'm a beginner to this and most of the explanation is not understood. I know that will work. However please don't feel awkward for my little knowledge. Thanks.

Comment: @Debis - I'll update my answer in 5-10 minutes with some more notes to make it easier for you to understand. Can you let me know which line you have difficulty with?

Comment: @Debis - I've added some more notes. Let me know if you need any more help regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an 'E' operator in java. This would conflict with variable names for one thing. `double xE2=x*1e2;` In this case, xE2 is a variable name, but I do use 1e2 as a java literal.

Comment: So, you mean to say that the following will serve the purpose? System.out.println(x*1e2).

Comment: @debis yes, x*1e2 is a valid expression, and you can print out the result.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the exponent notation since it is a part of double literal. Try multiplying.

```
System.out.println(x * 10 * 10)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Kindly let me know if what I was trying to do, is not possible in Java or it is possible in Java but I was doing it incorrectly? If incorrect, please show me the right way. Thanks again.

Comment: e is used in a float literal which means it can be used when it is declared. I have decent knowledge but I haven't seen it being used with variables. In short, it is not possible to use it with variables

Comment: The term "literal" and the use of E is now clear as crystal to me. Thanks a sea dear.

Comment: I am happy I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read java.util.Math library documentation, it includes many scientific functions like Exponents: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Comment: Great. Thanks dear.